spring mongodb aggregation framework spring data
I have a aggregation flow in mongo spring which produce me following JSON (interesting sample only)
"pages2":[
      [
         {
            "_id":1,

And thats the code which is responsible for building this part
pipeline.add(addFields().addFieldWithValue("pages2", VariableOperators.mapItemsOf("pages")
     .as("page")
     .andApply(VariableOperators.mapItemsOf("$$page.elements").as("element")
     .andApply(ArrayOperators.First.firstOf(ArrayOperators.Filter
                                                .filter("$matche")
                                                .as("matche")
                                                .by(Eq.valueOf("$$matche.name")
                                                                .equalToValue(
                                                               "$$element.name"))))))
      .build());

Is there any option to make this code create something like this??
"pages2":[
    --> elements: [
         {
            "_id":1,

Adding this "elements" string before an sub array. I'm out of ideas currenlty
Thanks
Marcin
